# jQuery issue targeting the clicked element when there are multiple instances of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple instances on pills and I am trying to add a class to the one that's been click and only to that one.

Here's an example:

Instance One

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contentone" class="active" onclick="toggleActive($event)">One</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contenttwo" onclick="toggleActive($event)">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Instance Two

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contentone" class="active" onclick="toggleActive($event)">One</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contenttwo" onclick="toggleActive($event)">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have this function:

```
toggleActive(this) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Basically what is happening is that what I click on the instance of the second one (for example), it's changing the pill in the first one.

I need it just to affect the clicked element and not the other one.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you've defined it somewhere at a global level, `$event` will be `undefined`. Even if you have defined it, it won't contain any useful information about the event that's raised as your code is expecting, hence `$(this)` is not what you expect it to be.

To fix this, and improve the code, stop using `on*` event attributes entirely and attach your event handlers unobtrusively. As you're already using jQuery, here's how you do that:

```js
$('.nav-pills li a').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active'); // note toggleClass here, to allow selection/deselection
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contentone" class="active">One</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contenttwo">Two</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contentone" class="active">One</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contenttwo">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to using function toggleActive()

```js
   $(function () {
        toggleActive = function (e) {
            $("a").removeClass('active')
            $(e).addClass('active');
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contentone" class="active" onclick="toggleActive(this)">One</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contenttwo" onclick="toggleActive(this)">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

you can first, remove all  the Active class and then add the Active Class, to  item clicked